# Can I make my nginx error_log save the whole stacktrace?

Tags: nginx, django, fast-user-switching

I have an Django app running on fastcgi and when there's an exception it seems like it getting cut off in the logs `error.log`:

```
2012/06/10 19:25:55 [error] 1416#0: *19219 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/deploy/.virtualenv/mediapop/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flup/server/fcgi_base.py", line 574, in run
    protocolStatus, appStatus = self.server.handler(self)
  File "/home/deploy/.virtualenv/mediapop/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flup/server/fcgi_base.py", line 1159, in handler
    result = self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/deploy/.virtualenv/mediapop/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 273, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/home/deploy/.virtualenv/mediapop/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 169, in get_response
    response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
  File "/home/deploy/.virtualenv/mediapop/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 209, in handle_uncaught_exception
    'request':request
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1154, in error
    self._log(ERROR, msg, args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1246, in _log
    self.handle(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1256, in handle
    self.callHandlers(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1293, in callHandlers
    hdlr.handle(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 740, in handle
    self.emit(record)
  File "/home/deploy/.virtualenv/mediapop/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 101, in emit
    html_message=html_message)
  File "/home/deploy/.virtualenv/mediapop/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 96, in mail_admins
    mail.send(fail_silently=fail_silently)
  File "/home/deploy/.virtualenv/mediapop/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 251, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/home/deploy/.virtualenv/mediapop/li
```

Can I remedy that so I have the full stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend keeping your web server error log and your application error log separate. This neatly separates two layers of your stack, as the web server logs will contain the http-level errors, while the app log will contain exceptions thrown by your code and other custom logging you generate.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238081/how-do-you-log-server-errors-on-django-sites) has more on Django error logging, including recommendations for other options to log your Django stack traces.